# How can I deny xdebug connections in PHPStorm that are already set as approved?

Tags: phpstorm

I frequently have multiple projects open in PHPStorm, I think I must have accidentally accepted xdebug connections for the wrong project in some, now at times the debugger starts and opens the wrong project.
Where can I find the config file that keeps track of these so I can remove incorrect entries?

Comment: Most likely `Settings | PHP | Servers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | PHP | Servers` -- that is the only thing that matches your description.

**P.S.**
The settings path above is for PhpStorm **v8.0.1 and older**; for **v8.0.2 and newer** it will be slightly different: `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Servers`.